# What is "twelve fingers" in Pranavayu?

Tags: agamas, tantra, kashmiri-shaivism

In Shiva Sutra, III.4 it is mentioned about Pranavayu that

> this is a way of meditation to concentrate on Prana i.e. on the expiration and inspiration of breath from the centre of the body upto a distance of ***twelve fingers*** in the external space. The mind has to be concentrated on the starting point of the breath from the centre and the ending point at a distance of twelve fingers from the center which is known as the end of ***dvaadashaanta*** the distance of twelve fingers. The external distance is known as ***baahya dvaadashaanta*** and internal (the starting point) is known as ***antar dvaadashaanta*** . One has to concentrate on the points Where the expiring and inspiring breaths stop for a split seconds.

My question is what is twelve fingers in this context ?

Comment: It is just talking about the distance. The distance from the index finger to the lil finger, when they are joined with each other, is the distance of 4 fingers. 3 times that is the distance of 12 fingers. Sometimes it is used to point out exactly where from a particular point one needs to fix his gaze upon or one needs to fix his mind upon.

Comment: You may post an answer instead. @Rickross

Comment: What is 9 inches, the length of nose ? @Uday

Comment: I think swami laxmanjoo site may have article on this

Comment: @Uday Is it ok if I add it to my answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Rickross and Uday already mentioned in the comment, I'll add it as answer.

*"twelve fingers"* in Pranavayu is nothing but a distance unit. The distance from the index finger to the little finger, when they are joined with each other, is the distance of 4 fingers. 
3 times that is the distance of 12 fingers. Sometimes it is used to point out exactly where from a particular point one needs to fix his gaze upon or one needs 
to fix his mind upon.

To understand this we can put it in a equation below:

> 4 fingers(minus thumb) multiplies by 3 == 9 inches == distance of twelve fingers from the center.

According to [Gheranda Samhita FIFTH LESSON.86-87:](http://hinduonline.co/DigitalLibrary/SmallBooks/GherandaSamhitaSanEng.pdf)

> When exhaling, the stream of air measures about 12 fingers(9 inches)from the nose.When singing, its length increase to 16 fingers; when talking, to 24 fingers.During strenous exercises, to even more.

Comment: Is this meditation even possible. How can we measure when one is in meditation?

Comment: Well! That I have got no idea about. All I can tell you is, these things must be learned under the Guru for proper execution. And it is unfortunate for you that I am not a Guru :D  @Ram

Comment: hmmm yes :). Do you know the benefit of this difficult meditation?

Comment: Yes certainly that I know. @Ram

Comment: what are the benefits apart from the usual meditation benefits?